# とする vs にする difference

Tags: particles

みことばを確かなもの**と**された

みことばを確かなもの**に**された

Any difference?

Comment: https://ja.hinative.com/questions/9110625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

とする implies the chooser has authority, whereas にする is neutral.

For example, if you say `ランチ休憩は30分にする` it simply means the chooser decided to make it 30 minutes, possibly just for themselves. If you say `ランチ休憩は30分とする` then it implies authority so it implies it was decided for multiple people.

Hence, you can say 「私のお弁当はカツカレーにしてください」 but not 「私のお弁当はカツカレーとしてください」. On the other hand, it's natural to say 「税率は15%とする」but a bit odd to say 「税率は15%にする」 because it sounds overly casual for the topic.